# -bash: export: `“JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home”': not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to set up Java and Hadoop on my Mac machine, and in doing so, I am using this command:

```
$ echo export “JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)” >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

However, when I type source ~/.bash_profile it gives me this error:

```
-bash: export: `“JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home”': not a valid identifier
```

Why is it saying this?

Comment: `“` is not `"`. These characters are not interchangeable.

Comment: And your code is running the `java_home` program just once, when you modify your `.bash_profile`, not every time your `.bash_profile` is sourced -- are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would more correctly look like:

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Note:

- Standard ASCII quotes, not curly "smart quotes", are used.
- Single quotes are used to ensure that the command substitution is not evaluated before the `echo` is run, but instead is added to your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: This lead me to find my issue.   Checking the basic path to ensure it was working did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

## My issue

I am on a MAC OS & was getting a similar error I got the following.

```bash
java -version

# -bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: Bad CPU type in executable
```

For my `~/.bash_profile`

I had the very end of my bash profile set as:

```bash
# set JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home"
PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# set M2_HOME
export M2_HOME=""
PATH="${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

## Fix

I just needed to update it too:

```bash
# set JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk"
PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# set M2_HOME
export M2_HOME=""
PATH="${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I just had to remove the `/Contents/Home` from the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Now when i run `java -version` i get:

```bash
# openjdk version "18.0.2" 2022-07-19
# OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)
# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-61, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This effected my attempt to build using terminal in the IDE of `IntelliJ IDEA`.  I was trying to run my jar file and it initially was a deceiving error.